# Libpcap to filter both src and dst port

Tags: python, libpcap, tcpdump

I'm using the example code provided by `pylibpcap` [here](https://github.com/signed0/pylibpcap/blob/master/examples/sniff.py) which is used as: `sniff.py <interface> <expr>`. the `<expr>` seems to be using the same syntax as `tcpdump` but I can't make it filter both source and destination port 5000 at the same time.

Using tcpdump it would be like `tcpdump -i eth1 -n tcp port 5000`.

Using the sniff.py I tried things like `sniff.py eth1 "src port 5000 and dst port 5000"` but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should work. The syntax is called "BPF" by the way if that helps you find resources.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `src port 5000 or dst port 5000` (which is the same thing as just `port 5000`)? With the `and` you'll only get packets that are from 5000 to 5000.

Comment: I've also tried those but they don't capture both ways. Only one :( This makes me believe that this is a code issue...

Answer (score 2):

libpcap (or WinPcap on Windows; it's a port of libpcap to Windows) is the library that handles the filter syntax in question; tcpdump uses libpcap, and pylibpcap is a wrapper around libpap, so they will both use the same filter syntax.

The syntax for the filters is, in current versions of libpcap, documented in [the pcap-filter man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html).  In that syntax, `port N` is equivalent to `src port N or dst port N`; `src port N`, `dst port N`, and `port N` check TCP *and* UDP *and* SCTP ports.  `tcp port N`, `tcp src port N`, and `tcp dst port N` check only for TCP ports.

Try using `port 5000` in both tcpdump *and* your program.  If *both* of them capture traffic only in one direction, the problem is obviously not in your code.  Try using `port 5000 or (vlan and port 5000)` (you'll have to quote it in tcpdump, i.e.

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -n "tcp port 5000 or (vlan and tcp port 5000)"
```

and see if that helps.